# How to get the order of each day in a week?

Tags: ios, calendar, weekday

I wonder if there is a way to know how each day of a week ordered? I know in the Gregorian calendar, property 'weekday' indicates 1-7, and
Sunday is represented by 1. But when I change the region(setting->General->Language &Region->Region) to Russia, the Apple's calendar app displays 'M'as the first day of a week, while United States displays 'S' as the first day of a week.
How can I work out this programmatically? Any idea, thanks advance.

[image: This is a screenshot of Apple's calendar app]

Comment: `firstWeekDay` property of `NSCalendar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set programmatically start day of week by following code.

**To get first day of week after setting**

```
- (NSDate*)firstDayOfWeek
{
    NSCalendar* calender = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] copy];
    [calender setFirstWeekday:2]; //Override locale to make week start on Monday
    NSDate* startOfTheWeek;
    NSTimeInterval interval;
    [calender rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfTheWeek interval:&interval forDate:self];
    return startOfTheWeek;
}
```

**To set First day of week**

```
    [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] setFirstWeekday:2]; //Override locale to make week start on Monday
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. firstWeekday is what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday]
```

Comment: I am just curious my answer is earlier and it is right,why not accept my answer?

Comment: Sorry about that, Leo. It's my fault. My device is iPhone 4s, your answer is not wholly displayed, and I missed 'firstWeekday]'. What can I do to make up to it?

Comment: Well,no need.It does not matter

Answer (score 0):

NSCalendar has a property named **firstWeekday** which indicates the index of the first weekday of the receiver.

[NSCalendar documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/firstWeekday)

Comment: Seems everybody know this, I'm so lame. Thank you very much for your help!